# Not able to apply variables updates correctly while implementing a multi theme website

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I have a Next.js app and a globals file with all the themes:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Inconsolata, monospace;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}

:root {
  --bg-color: #262a33;
  --main-color: #43ffaf;
  --sub-color: #526777;
  --sub-alt-color: #1f232c;
  --text-color: #e5f7ef;
  --error-color: #ff5f5f;
}

[data-theme="superuser"] {
  background-color: var(--bg-color) !important;
  --bg-color: #262a33;
  --main-color: #43ffaf;
  --sub-color: #526777;
  --sub-alt-color: #1f232c;
  --text-color: #e5f7ef;
  --error-color: #ff5f5f;
}
```

I am using Redux to manage the state and select the theme:

```js
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { State } from "../store/reducer";

export default function Layout({ children }: { children: any }) {
    const {
        preferences: { theme }
    } = useSelector((state: State) => state);

    return (
        <div data-theme={theme}>
            <Navbar />
            <main>{children}</main>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Not sure if this is the right way, but it works; the problem is when a different theme is selected, its respective `bg-color` doesn't get used, and instead the `bg-color` specified in the `root` gets used.

How do I fix this? Also when the page is being reloaded initially the navbar's theme is the default theme which is specified in `root`; after it has loaded completely its theme changes to the selected theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are setting your variables on `:root`, aka `html`, as it's the top parent, so any element in the page inherits them, which is correct.

Then, and here is the problem, you are setting `data-theme` on that `div` in your `Layout`, which is a child of `body`, so the changed variables apply only to what's nested inside it, not on `body`, `html`...

## Solution

You could fix this issue by setting the theme on `html`, with an `useEffect`, as an example, like so:

```js
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { State } from "../store/reducer";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Layout({ children }: { children: any }) {
  const {
    preferences: { theme },
  } = useSelector((state: State) => state);

  useEffect(() => {
    // set the theme on the root, aka html element
     document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", theme || "");
  }, [theme]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <main>{children}</main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This way you could keep your CSS as you already did; just remove the below line that you have over there, as not needed anymore:

```
background-color: var(--bg-color) !important;
```

For your other issue, the page taking some time before applying the selected theme on load, you could read: [Implement Dark/Light mode: How to fix the flicker of incorrect theme?](https://dev.to/tusharshahi/react-nextjs-dark-mode-theme-switcher-how-i-fixed-my-flicker-problem-5b54#usingLocalStorage)

Comment: It worked, but it doesn't apply themes when an error page is displayed

Comment: I think using cookies to save themes will fix all of the issues